# i want a anchor should act like and input type submit button

Tags: javascript, html

i want a anchor should act like and input type submit button.
i am using a jquery plugin library that actually uses input type submit but i have styled my buttons on anchors. i dont want to use

```
<input type="button">
```

or

```
<input type="submit">
```

i want to use anchors such as

```
<a href="javascript to submit the form" ></a>
```

and here is my jquery code where i want to use

```
 {
     var submit = $('<button type="submit" />');
     submit.html(settings.submit);                            
 }
 $(this).append(submit);
 }
 if (settings.cancel) {
     /* if given html string use that */
     if (settings.cancel.match(/>$/)) {
         var cancel = $(settings.cancel);
         /* otherwise use button with given string as text */
     } else {
         var cancel = $('<button type="cancel" />');
```

how to use anchors instead of button.

Comment: Somehow your JS code is incomplete. Styling the buttons as anchors in much better IMO as your code will also work if JS is disabled. But in any way, `<button type="submit" />` is wrong. `<button>` is a generic button element, it has no type attribute and you have to bind event handlers to it so that it does something. You should always choose the element that is the closest to what you want to **do**, not how it **looks** like (that is what CSS is for).

Comment: `$('a').click(function() {$('form').submit()});`

Comment: i know. actually i just showed an example of code. just tell me how to use anchor instead of <button type="submit" />

Comment: @Felix - "`<button>` is a generic button element, it has no type attribute ..". It does you know, see http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-button-element.html#attr-button-type and http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-type-BUTTON

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want an anchor tag to act like a button just do this

```
<!--YOUR FORM-->
<form id="submit_this">.....</form>
<a id="fakeanchor" href="#"></a>

<script>
    $("a#fakeanchor").click(function()
    {
    $("#submit_this").submit();
    return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this is also very use full in near future :) . thanx :)

Comment: On input tags, sometimes I would use the 'name' attribute on the input element to specify which action I want to perform. If I use your code snippet with the anchor tag, how I would I push that value up when submitting?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using jQuery, just use `$()` to select the `form` element, and call `submit` on it; hook all this up to the anchor via `$()` to find the anchor and `click` to hook up the handler:

```
$("selector_for_the_anchor").click(function() {
    $("selector_for_the_form").submit();
    return false;
});
```

Probably best to `return false;` to cancel the click on the anchor.

---

**Off-topic**: But note that this makes your page completely unusable without JavaScript, as well as making it confusing even for JavaScript-enabled browsers employed by users requiring assistive technologies (screenreaders, etc.). It makes the markup completely un-semantic. But since you'd said quite clearly that this was what you wanted to do...

Answer (score 2):

```
<a id='anchor' href="javascript to submit the form" ></a>
```

now you can use jquery to add an event handler

```
$('#anchor').click(function (e) {
  // do some work

 // prevent the default anchor behaviour
 e.preventDefault();
})
```

now you can style your anchor as you wish and it will act as a regular button

Answer (score 2):

And what about:

```
<form id="formOne">
        ...
   <a href="..." onclick="formOne.submit()">link here</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use input of type image (it works as a submit button for a form) or in jquery:

```
$("a").click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $('form').submit();
})
```

Comment: **All** anchors should submit **all** forms? ;-)

Comment: no it's just for an example. I haven't got a crystal ball to know what id, or class names does the OP have...

Comment: It's fairly misleading without *something* saying what the selectors do.