# Better dropdown with bootstrap

Tags: forms, button, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I try to use dropdowns of bootstrap, it's work the problem is esthetic. :

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns

I have this code :

```
<div class="dropdown">
     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Colléctivités <b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
     <?php
         foreach ($collectivite as $key => $value) {
              echo '<form method="post" action="wbx.php"><li><button type="submit" class="btn" style="margin:0px;" name="cookie" value='.$value.'>'.$value.'</button>    </li></form>';
         }

      ?>
   </ul>
</div>
```

WITHOUT PHP :

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Colléctivités <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <form method="post" action="wbx.php">
            <li>
                <button type="submit" class="btn" style="margin:0px;" name="cookie" value=heeloWorld.net>world.net</button>
            </li>
        </form>                    
    </ul>
</div>
```

But the result is very basic... not really good. I use **button** because i **submit** some data with **form**
So if i want something like this, how can i do ?

[image]

**EDIT solution**

I Use this : the alert is ok, i have the good value, but the submit doesn't work.

```
<?php
    foreach ($collectivite as $key => $value) {
        $name = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]+#i', '', $value);
        echo '<form method="post" action="wbx.php" id='.$name.'>
            <input type="hidden"  name="cookie"   value='.$value.'>
        </form>';
    }
?>
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Colléctivités <b     class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <?php
            foreach ($collectivite as $key => $value) {
                    $name = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]+#i', '', $value);

                    echo '<li>
                        <input type="hidden"  name="cookie"   value='.$value.'>
                        <a class="myformlink" data-formname="#'.$name.'" >'.$value.'</a>
                    </li>';
            }

        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.myformlink').click(function(){
            $($(this).data('formname')).submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use a button tu submit your form. You can use a regular anchor to do it. please check this link : [i want a anchor should act like and input type submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086816/i-want-a-anchor-should-act-like-and-input-type-submit-button)

this way your dropdown will look like the one in your example.

Hope it helps :)

*Edit : In French we write "Collectivités" ;) just kiddin...*

EDIT : sample of a code with data attributes

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Colléctivités <b     class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <form method="post" action="wbx.php" id="formGujanMestras">
            <li>
                <a class="myformlink" id="linkC" data-formname="#formGujanMestras">value1</a>
            </li>
        </form>
        <form method="post" action="wbx.php" id="formLaHume">
            <li>
                <a class="myformlink" id="linkD" data-formname="#formLaHume">value2</a>
            </li>
        </form>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.myformlink').click(function(){
            alert('hey martial i gonna submit ' + $(this).data('formname'));
            $($(this).data('formname')).submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In english we write : "You haven't". See my **EDIT** ;)

Comment: By the way, be careful with your `foreach` loop : you gonna have several items with the same ID, it won't be a valid HTML page

Comment: **$(".dropdown li a").click(function()** But it doesn't work. I clik on the link nothing happened.

Comment: If you have two values in `$collectivite`, you gonna create two forms with the same ID `formC`. that's probably why your jQuery doesn't fire - You should create a class `myclass`, assign it to your anchors so your jquery will look like $`(".myclass").click(function(){` - then, use a data attribute to give an attribute to your anchor, containing the forms name for example, so you can use the attribute in your jQuery to submit the right form. Hope it helps :)

Comment: take a look at my edit with a sample of dataattribute to fire the right form. you will have to edit your `foreach` in order to give different names to each forms

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33640/discussion-between-martiale-and-pascamel)